# replace NA with mean of column groups

Tags: r, lapply

I want to find the means of all values in groups of columns.  A given group of columns might contain missing observations.  I want to replace the missing observations within a group of columns by the mean for that group of columns.  In my case the number of columns per group is a constant, `years`.

Below is code that does this.  However, I am hoping someone might provide code that is much more efficient.  The `lapply` finds the mean for a given group of columns.  However, I have not yet come up with a similar approach for replacing the missing observations.  Thank you for any advice.

Here is an example data set:

```
my.first.year <- 1980
my.last.year  <- 1982
years <- (my.last.year - my.first.year) + 1

x = read.table(text = "
 city county   state      a80    a81    a82    b80     b81   b82
  1      B       AA        2      20    200     4       8     12
  2      B       AA        4      NA    400     5       9     NA
  1      C       AA        6      60     NA    NA      10     14
  2      C       AA       NA      80    800     7      11     15    
", sep = "", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

(2 + 4 + 6 + 20 + 60 + 80 + 200 + 400 + 800) / 9
(4 + 5 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 + 11 + 12 + 14 + 15) / 10

my.means <- lapply( seq(4, ncol(x), years) , function(i) { mean(unlist(x[,i : (i+years-1) ]) , na.rm=TRUE) } )
my.means

x2 <- x

x2[,(3+years*0+1):(3+years*1)][is.na(x2[,(3+years*0+1):(3+years*1)])] = my.means[[1]]
x2[,(3+years*1+1):(3+years*2)][is.na(x2[,(3+years*1+1):(3+years*2)])] = my.means[[2]]
```

Here is the result:

```
#   city county state      a80      a81      a82 b80 b81  b82
# 1    1      B    AA   2.0000  20.0000 200.0000 4.0   8 12.0
# 2    2      B    AA   4.0000 174.6667 400.0000 5.0   9  9.5
# 3    1      C    AA   6.0000  60.0000 174.6667 9.5  10 14.0
# 4    2      C    AA 174.6667  80.0000 800.0000 7.0  11 15.0
```

Comment: The group of columns is not given by their names, e.g a* and b*? It is not clear how you group the data , in the code you take 3 (years) columns then , the 3 after...

Comment: Ignoring the first 3 columns there are three columns in each group.  The plyr answers are nice, but I would prefer a solution in base.

Comment: @MarkMiller I've added one, by converting data from wide to long format, which I think makes more sense. It is similar in spirit to agstudy's answer.

Comment: @MarkMiller. Another solutions using base R. Shorter, more concise code :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another solution using `reshape` from base R, an often forgotten function with amazing power.

```
x2 = reshape(x, direction = 'long', varying = 4:9, sep = "")
x2[,c('a', 'b')] = apply(x2[,c('a', 'b')], 2, function(y){
  y[is.na(y)] = mean(y, na.rm = T)
  return(y)
})
x3 = reshape(x2, direction = 'wide', idvar = names(x2)[1:3], timevar = 'time', 
 sep = "")
```

Here is how it works. First, we reshape the data to long format, where `a` and `b` become columns and the years become rows. Second, we replace NAs in columns `a` and `b` with their respective means. Finally, we reshape the data back to the wide format. `reshape` is a confusing function, but working through the examples on the help page will get you up to speed.

**EDIT**

To reorder columns, you can do

```
x3[,names(x)]
```

To replace the rownames, you can do

```
rownames(x3) = 1:NROW(x3)
```

Comment: That is nice!  I would refer to use base R.  However, the columns become reordered and multiple extraneous id columns are created and added throughout the final data set.  I suppose a clever re-ordering of columns by name could adjust for that.

Comment: See my edit for how to reorder columns and to replace rownames.

Answer (score 3):

One answer, but maybe not the simplest one, which uses the `plyr` and `reshape2` packages :

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
```

First, transform your data frame from a "wide" to a "long" format (one observation per line) and create a `groups` column :

```
mx <- melt(x, id.vars=c("city","country","state"))
mx$groups[mx$variable %in% c("a80","a81","a82")] <- 1
mx$groups[mx$variable %in% c("b80","b81","b82")] <- 2
head(mx)
```

The first lines of your data should now look like this :

```
  city county state variable value groups
1    1      B    AA      a80     2      1
2    2      B    AA      a80     4      1
3    1      C    AA      a80     6      1
4    2      C    AA      a80    NA      1
5    1      B    AA      a81    20      1
6    2      B    AA      a81    NA      1
```

Then you can use `ddply` to replace the missing values by the means :

```
mx <- ddply(mx, .(groups), function(df) {df$value[is.na(df$value)] <- mean(df$value, na.rm=TRUE); return(df)})
```

And finally use `dcast` to get your data back to "long" format :

```
x <- dcast(mx, city + county + state ~ variable)
x
```

Which gives :

```
  city county state      a80      a81      a82 b80 b81  b82
1    1      B    AA   2.0000  20.0000 200.0000 4.0   8 12.0
2    1      C    AA   6.0000  60.0000 174.6667 9.5  10 14.0
3    2      B    AA   4.0000 174.6667 400.0000 5.0   9  9.5
4    2      C    AA 174.6667  80.0000 800.0000 7.0  11 15.0
```

Comment: @Arun For me it is not clear how the Op would group the data. Even what you propose is more logic here, it groups data by years, 3 by 3..

Comment: @Arun, yes, if there are many groups it is certainly better to do it your way.

Comment: @Arun +1 The necessary information is essentially contained within the varying column names. I combined the `melt()` idea from here and processed `variable`, and then worked on that.

Answer (score 2):

I use your code , and I add one line `na.fill` ( even I don't like your grouping by 3 columns).

**EDIT**

The `na.fill` is the zoo package.  It was so handy , that I thought it is in the base package. Next time I restart my session before posting here.

```
ll <- lapply( seq(4, ncol(x), years) , 
        function(i) { 
          m <- mean(unlist(x[,i : (i+years-1) ]) , na.rm=TRUE) 
          na.fill(x[,i : (i+years-1) ],m)      ## here the line I add 
          } 
        )
do.call(cbind,ll)   



    a80      a81      a82 b80 b81  b82
[1,]   2.0000  20.0000 200.0000 4.0   8 12.0
[2,]   4.0000 174.6667 400.0000 5.0   9  9.5
[3,]   6.0000  60.0000 174.6667 9.5  10 14.0
[4,] 174.6667  80.0000 800.0000 7.0  11 15.0
```

I would use something like this to select columns :

```
lapply(c('a','b'),function(i){
       cols.group <- regmatches(colnames(x),
                                regexpr(paste(i,"[0-9]+",sep=''),colnames(x)))
       m <- mean(unlist(x[,cols.group]) , na.rm=TRUE) 
       na.fill(x[,cols.group ],m) 
})


do.call(cbind,ll)   
cbind(x[,!grepl("(a|b)[0-9]+",colnames(x))],do.call(cbind,ll))

  city county state      a80      a81      a82 b80 b81  b82
1    1      B    AA   2.0000  20.0000 200.0000 4.0   8 12.0
2    2      B    AA   4.0000 174.6667 400.0000 5.0   9  9.5
3    1      C    AA   6.0000  60.0000 174.6667 9.5  10 14.0
4    2      C    AA 174.6667  80.0000 800.0000 7.0  11 15.0
```

Comment: It would be nice to return the `city`, `county` and `state` variables too. Couldn't you assign the output from `na.fill()` to those same columns of `x`? Something like `x[cols.group] <- na.fill(x[,cols.group ],m)`? +1 for `na.fill()` (I did it that step by hand as I was unaware of that function!).

Comment: @GavinSimpson I update my answer. I can't use your idea since the lapply will be applied in the original x.

Answer (score 2):

You are making things more difficult for yourself having the data stored in a wide format as compared to a long format. My Take on this would be to convert to a long format using `melt()` from the **reshape2** package. Using your data

```
my.first.year <- 1980
my.last.year  <- 1982

x <- read.table(text = "
 city county   state      a80    a81    a82    b80     b81   b82
  1      B       AA        2      20    200     4       8     12
  2      B       AA        4      NA    400     5       9     NA
  1      C       AA        6      60     NA    NA      10     14
  2      C       AA       NA      80    800     7      11     15    
", sep = "", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

First we `melt()` `x` and do some manipulations of `variable` to get the group and the year

```
require(reshape2)

xx <- melt(x, id.vars = c("city","county","state"))
## Add year and group variables by process the `variable` column
xx <- transform(xx, year = as.numeric(sub("^[a-zA-Z]", "", variable)),
                group = regmatches(variable, regexpr("^[a-zA-Z]", variable)), 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
## format start and end years as per way stored in column names
start <- as.numeric(substring(my.first.year, first = 3))
end <- as.numeric(substring(my.last.year, first = 3))
```

`start` and `end` are formatted versions of your start and end years without the century part. At this point `xx` looks like

```
> head(xx)
  city county state variable value year group
1    1      B    AA      a80     2   80     a
2    2      B    AA      a80     4   80     a
3    1      C    AA      a80     6   80     a
4    2      C    AA      a80    NA   80     a
5    1      B    AA      a81    20   81     a
6    2      B    AA      a81    NA   81     a
```

Next I use one of the base R split-apply-combine idioms, and `split()` `xx` by `group`

```
xxs <- split(xx, f = xx$group)
```

Then `lapply()` can apply a function to subset by `year` for the years indicated to lie in or between `start`:`end`. I compute the mean of the `value` variable for the subset values, removing `NA`s. The we return the mean.

```
foo <- function(x, start, end) {
  take <- with(x, year >= start & year <= end)
  xbar <- mean(x[take, "value"], na.rm = TRUE)
  xbar
}

lapply(xxs, foo, start = start, end = end)
```

This gives:

```
> lapply(xxs, foo, start = start, end = end)
$a
[1] 174.6667

$b
[1] 9.5
```

As for a function to replace the `NA`s, a minor modification of `foo()` achieves this:

```
foor <- function(x, start, end) {
  take <- with(x, year >= start & year <= end)
  xbar <- mean(x[take, "value"], na.rm = TRUE)
  nas <- is.na(x[take, "value"]) ## which are NA?
  x[take, "value"][nas] <- xbar  ## replace NA with xbar
  x                              ## return
}
```

To get back a data frame I wrap this in `do.call()` which arranges to call `rbind()` on the output from `lapply()`:

```
xx2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(xxs, foor, start = start, end = end))
```

which gives:

```
> head(xx2)
    city county state variable    value year group
a.1    1      B    AA      a80   2.0000   80     a
a.2    2      B    AA      a80   4.0000   80     a
a.3    1      C    AA      a80   6.0000   80     a
a.4    2      C    AA      a80 174.6667   80     a
a.5    1      B    AA      a81  20.0000   81     a
a.6    2      B    AA      a81 174.6667   81     a
```

If you need to go back to the original format of data, then `dcast()` (also from `reshape2`) is your friend:

```
x2 <- dcast(xx2[, 1:5], city + county + state ~ variable)

> head(x)
  city county state a80 a81 a82 b80 b81 b82
1    1      B    AA   2  20 200   4   8  12
2    2      B    AA   4  NA 400   5   9  NA
3    1      C    AA   6  60  NA  NA  10  14
4    2      C    AA  NA  80 800   7  11  15
> head(x2)
  city county state      a80      a81      a82 b80 b81  b82
1    1      B    AA   2.0000  20.0000 200.0000 4.0   8 12.0
2    1      C    AA   6.0000  60.0000 174.6667 9.5  10 14.0
3    2      B    AA   4.0000 174.6667 400.0000 5.0   9  9.5
4    2      C    AA 174.6667  80.0000 800.0000 7.0  11 15.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I could have given the check mark to any of the answers, but I prefer Ramnath's answer because it is entirely in base R and seems very straight-forward.  However, when I tried to use his answer I realized that I needed separate means for each of numerous states.  So, I modified his answer as follows:

```
my.first.year <- 1980
my.last.year  <- 1982
years <- (my.last.year - my.first.year) + 1

x = read.table(text = "
 city county   state      a80    a81    a82    b80     b81   b82
  1      B       AA        2      20    200     4       8     12
  2      B       AA        4      NA    400     5       9     NA
  1      C       AA        6      60     NA    NA      10     14
  2      C       AA       NA      80    800     7      11     15

  1      A       BB        1       2      1     2       2      2
  2      A       BB        2      NA      1     2       2     NA
  1      B       BB        1       1     NA    NA       2      2
  2      B       BB       NA       2      1     2       2     10
", sep = "", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
x

x2 = reshape(x, direction = 'long', varying = 4:9, sep = "")

x2 <- x2[order(x2$state, x2$time),]

x2[,c('a', 'b')] = apply(x2[,c('a', 'b')], 2, function(z) {
      sapply(split(z, x2$state), 
      function(y) {  y[is.na(y)] = mean(y, na.rm = T)  
      return(y)   }) 
      })
x2

x3 <- reshape(x2, direction = 'wide', idvar = names(x2)[1:3], timevar = 'time', 
 sep = "")

x3[,names(x)]
```

This code seems to work.  Although, for some reason I needed to order `x2` by `state`.  I do not entirely understand the `return` statement.  If I find that the code does not work with future data sets I will edit this post to address the issue.